# Rails javascript_include_tag doesnt work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to make basic structure of my project to work out. In my "Master" file i have a line which call main.js.coffee script file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  "application", 'main' %>
```

in my main i have call to the next js files :

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./controllers/main/


./controllers/main/ contains just 1 single file  mainIndexCtrl.js.coffee
```

so here is the structure:

[image]

So on call of url:port/main/index application.html.erb is called which call to main.js.coffee which than call to mainIndexCtrl.js.coffee, or more like that what i think it does, because doesnt matter what i do i cant get rid of folowing error:

[image]

I am VERY new to Rails, so basicly i really dont know what to do because this error doesnt exactly saying anything to me.

Main.js.coffee :

```
    # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

#= require_self
#= require_tree ./controllers/main/
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your main.js.coffe file. Either correct the syntax/code error in the file or remove it from your `javascript_include_tag` (like: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application"  %>`) Also, it would make sense to include this file in your application.js, if it is to be used, to take full advantage of the asset pipeline....

Comment: Well, main.js.coffee is a coffescript file, so it must have the appropriate formatting and syntax for such a file. You may be able to spot the invalid stuff at a glance, or maybe a tool like http://www.coffeelint.org/, a good editor like RubyMine will usually highlight errors for you. Otherwise, remove it all and start adding it back until you add the line that is giving you the error...

Comment: The first line is indented, that might cause it, but you probably don't need that and the application.js...

Comment: ive tryed to remove everything adn it still fails whn i have completely empty main.js.coffee file. how is this possible?

Comment: Delete the entire file, adding any relevant bits to application.js, and make sure your helper looks like the one in the answer...

Comment: Also, mainIndexCtrl.js.coffee isn't in line with rails naming conventions... (but this is not the problem)

Comment: problem was that my application didnt understood coffee script, so ofcourse it couldnt load coffee scripts.